# Change FileVault recovery key from institutional to personal recovery key

Tags: macos, high-sierra, filevault

Upon leaving my old job, I was given my old Mac which I've used for years and got attached to it, I realised it has an institutional recovery key but I'd like to change that to a personal recovery key so I can easily store somewhere safe.
Is this an easy process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by opening up Terminal and using the FDESetup tool,  I run  `sudo fdesetup changerecovery -personal -keychain` and it worked. 
Terminal prompted for password to unlock the disk but worked